# Changing nameservers for a domain on GoDaddy

Tags: domains, web-hosting, nameserver

I am redoing a website for a friend of mine. The domain was purchased on GoDaddy. The hosting was purchased elsewhere. After having problems with the hosting company and making some updates I decided to switch the hosting to Network Solutions.

I have purchased the hosting from NS and just want to set the new NS nameservers on GoDaddy for the domain. I tried entering in the FTP server name from NS but it said it was not registered. Any help would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the DNS servers from Network Solutions and set them in the GoDaddy control panel (under Domains, click on the domain in question, then click set nameservers).[image: GoDaddy Domain Manager]

It should be something like:

```
dns1.networksolutions.com
dns2.networksolutions.com
```

(In my screenshot, I have ns1.dreamhost.com ns2. ns3.)

You can put more that 3 nameservers in the GoDaddy control panel, but you should enter at least two.

UPDATE: Upload all your files to your new host. Once DNS propagates, your site will be served from the new web host (Network Solutions).

Comment: Kevin, Once I change those nameservers what is next? Obviously just changing those nameservers alone will not switch the hosting of the domain on GoDaddy over to my network solutions hosting, cause it doesn't know where to point to.

Comment: Did that solve your question?

Comment: Just for the record, I was working with the same issue: GoDaddy had my domain name, but NearlyFreeSpeech had my hosting. As Kevin described, changing the nameservers on GoDaddy was straightforward. Once I changed the nameservers, accessing my domain went to my hosting provider. The change propagated relatively quickly also (within a few minutes).

Comment: Dan, please click the check mark next to my answer, if it solved your issue. Thanks.