# Changing nameservers for a domain on GoDaddy

Tags: web-hosting, domains, nameserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing nameservers for a domain on GoDaddy](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13957/changing-nameservers-for-a-domain-on-godaddy)

I am redoing a website for a friend of mine.  The domain was purchased on GoDaddy.  The hosting was purchased elsewhere.  After having problems with the hosting company and making some updates I decided to switch the hosting to Network Solutions.

I have purchased the hosting from NS and just want to set the new NS nameservers on GoDaddy for the domain.  I tried entering in the FTP server name from NS but it said it was not registered.  Any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: -1 This is not a programming question.

Comment: @sra, webmasters would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: @Brandon Oh yes, there are so much by now I didn't know that one. And yes, you can call me blind, I dind't see it. Can I change the vote?